# DASH - Toggling modals and multiple inputs

Tags: python, modal-dialog, toggle, plotly-dash

I'm currently developing simple dashboard for my department using Dash Plotly and having a lot of issues understanding toggling of modals depending on multiple inputs.

Here is my script:

```
layout = dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                html.P('Select value:'),
                        dcc.Dropdown(['Value1','Value2','Value3'],
                                 id='dropdown',
                                 style={'height': '30px', 'width': '200px','align-items': 'center', 'justify-content': 'center'},
                                 multi=True),
                        html.Br(),
                html.P('Select observed period:'),
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id='date-picker-range',
                    min_date_allowed= date(2022, 1, 1),
                    initial_visible_month= date(2023, 1, 1),
                    end_date= datetime.today().date(),
                    display_format='DD.MM.YYYY'),

                html.Br(), html.Br(),
                dbc.Button("Execute process", id='button'),
                html.Br()
                ],
                width=3,
                style={"background-color": "#f8f9fa",'align-items': 'center'},
                ),

            dbc.Col(children=[
                                html.Div(id='output'),
                                ]),
    ])
])


@app.callback(
    Output("modal", "is_open"),
    [Input("close", "n_clicks")],
    [State("modal", "is_open")]
            )

def toggle_modal(n1,is_open):
    if n1:
        return not is_open
    return is_open

@app.callback(
    Output('output','children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('dropdown','value'),
     Input('date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
     Input('date-picker-range', 'end_date')]
             )

def update_output(n_clicks,
                  values,
                  start_date,
                  end_date):

    ctx = dash.callback_context
    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if trigger_id == "button":

        if start_date is not None:

            if values is not None:

                return 'Works!'

            else: # no value is selected
                return dbc.Modal(
                    [
                        dbc.ModalHeader("Warning"),
                        dbc.ModalBody("No value selected for values."),
                        dbc.ModalFooter(
                            dbc.Button(
                                "Close",
                                id="close"
                            )
                        ),
                    ],
                    id="modal",
                    is_open=True
                )
        else:#no start date is selected
            return dbc.Modal(
                [
                    dbc.ModalHeader("Warning"),
                    dbc.ModalBody("No value selected for date."),
                    dbc.ModalFooter(
                        dbc.Button(
                            "Close",
                            id="close",
                        )
                    ),
                ],
                id="modal", is_open=True
            )

    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

What I want to achieve/understand is to set up callback that will work in such way:

- if Value is None and click button - raise modal
- if Value is not None but start date is not selected and click button - raise modal
- if value is not None and click button execute code !
- if i change value in value dropdown or change date and click button - execute code!
- if i remove all values from values dropdown and click button - **raise modal again** (here my code stops working and I don't know how to handle it)

It only work until i choose values for input but when I remove them to None again, modals do not raise.

I hope I've described my problem sufficiently so you can help me out.

Thanks a lot!